# Archive list with only years and months

Tags: plugins, archives, list, wp-get-archives

I'm trying to show the archive list like that

```
<ul>
<li>Year</li>
<li>Month</li>
<li>Month</li>
<li>Month</li>
<li>Year</li>
<li>Month</li>
</ul>
```

and so on, with the relative link only on the month. I tried different solutions as the CG Archive plugin ( http://wordpress.pastebin.ca/209160 ) and that's the only kind of plugin I can use since I need to place the php output wherever I want and the other plugins/widgets I found doesn't let me do that. The problem is that it doesn't show anything at all! Do you know any alternative solutions to accomplis that? Really thanks in advance and sorry for my poor english.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Place this in your *functions.php* file or create a simple plugin...

```
/**
 * Display archive links based on year/month and format.
 *
 * The date archives will logically display dates with links to the archive post
 * page.
 *
 * The 'limit' argument will only display a limited amount of links, specified
 * by the 'limit' integer value. By default, there is no limit. The
 * 'show_post_count' argument will show how many posts are within the archive.
 * By default, the 'show_post_count' argument is set to false.
 *
 * For the 'format', 'before', and 'after' arguments, see {@link
 * get_archives_link()}. The values of these arguments have to do with that
 * function.
 *
 * @param string|array $args Optional. Override defaults.
 */
function wp_custom_archive($args = '') {
    global $wpdb, $wp_locale;

    $defaults = array(
        'limit' => '',
        'format' => 'html', 'before' => '',
        'after' => '', 'show_post_count' => false,
        'echo' => 1
    );

    $r = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );
    extract( $r, EXTR_SKIP );

    if ( '' != $limit ) {
        $limit = absint($limit);
        $limit = ' LIMIT '.$limit;
    }

    // over-ride general date format ? 0 = no: use the date format set in Options, 1 = yes: over-ride
    $archive_date_format_over_ride = 0;

    // options for daily archive (only if you over-ride the general date format)
    $archive_day_date_format = 'Y/m/d';

    // options for weekly archive (only if you over-ride the general date format)
    $archive_week_start_date_format = 'Y/m/d';
    $archive_week_end_date_format   = 'Y/m/d';

    if ( !$archive_date_format_over_ride ) {
        $archive_day_date_format = get_option('date_format');
        $archive_week_start_date_format = get_option('date_format');
        $archive_week_end_date_format = get_option('date_format');
    }

    //filters
    $where = apply_filters('customarchives_where', "WHERE post_type = 'post' AND post_status = 'publish'", $r );
    $join = apply_filters('customarchives_join', "", $r);

    $output = '<ul>';

        $query = "SELECT YEAR(post_date) AS `year`, MONTH(post_date) AS `month`, count(ID) as posts FROM $wpdb->posts $join $where GROUP BY YEAR(post_date), MONTH(post_date) ORDER BY post_date DESC $limit";
        $key = md5($query);
        $cache = wp_cache_get( 'wp_custom_archive' , 'general');
        if ( !isset( $cache[ $key ] ) ) {
            $arcresults = $wpdb->get_results($query);
            $cache[ $key ] = $arcresults;
            wp_cache_set( 'wp_custom_archive', $cache, 'general' );
        } else {
            $arcresults = $cache[ $key ];
        }
        if ( $arcresults ) {
            $afterafter = $after;
            foreach ( (array) $arcresults as $arcresult ) {
                $url = get_month_link( $arcresult->year, $arcresult->month );
                $year_url = get_year_link($arcresult->year);
                /* translators: 1: month name, 2: 4-digit year */
                $text = sprintf(__('%s'), $wp_locale->get_month($arcresult->month));
                $year_text = sprintf('%d', $arcresult->year);
                if ( $show_post_count )
                    $after = '&nbsp;('.$arcresult->posts.')' . $afterafter;
                $year_output = get_archives_link($year_url, $year_text, $format, $before, $after);              
                $output .= ( $arcresult->year != $temp_year ) ? $year_output : '';
                $output .= get_archives_link($url, $text, $format, $before, $after);

                $temp_year = $arcresult->year;
            }
        }

    $output .= '</ul>';

    if ( $echo )
        echo $output;
    else
        return $output;
}
```

---

"just the year's text" version:

```
/**
 * Display archive links based on year/month and format.
 *
 * The date archives will logically display dates with links to the archive post
 * page.
 *
 * The 'limit' argument will only display a limited amount of links, specified
 * by the 'limit' integer value. By default, there is no limit. The
 * 'show_post_count' argument will show how many posts are within the archive.
 * By default, the 'show_post_count' argument is set to false.
 *
 * For the 'format', 'before', and 'after' arguments, see {@link
 * get_archives_link()}. The values of these arguments have to do with that
 * function.
 *
 * @param string|array $args Optional. Override defaults.
 */
function wp_custom_archive($args = '') {
    global $wpdb, $wp_locale;

    $defaults = array(
        'limit' => '',
        'format' => 'html', 'before' => '',
        'after' => '', 'show_post_count' => false,
        'echo' => 1
    );

    $r = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );
    extract( $r, EXTR_SKIP );

    if ( '' != $limit ) {
        $limit = absint($limit);
        $limit = ' LIMIT '.$limit;
    }

    // over-ride general date format ? 0 = no: use the date format set in Options, 1 = yes: over-ride
    $archive_date_format_over_ride = 0;

    // options for daily archive (only if you over-ride the general date format)
    $archive_day_date_format = 'Y/m/d';

    // options for weekly archive (only if you over-ride the general date format)
    $archive_week_start_date_format = 'Y/m/d';
    $archive_week_end_date_format   = 'Y/m/d';

    if ( !$archive_date_format_over_ride ) {
        $archive_day_date_format = get_option('date_format');
        $archive_week_start_date_format = get_option('date_format');
        $archive_week_end_date_format = get_option('date_format');
    }

    //filters
    $where = apply_filters('customarchives_where', "WHERE post_type = 'post' AND post_status = 'publish'", $r );
    $join = apply_filters('customarchives_join', "", $r);

    $output = '<ul>';

        $query = "SELECT YEAR(post_date) AS `year`, MONTH(post_date) AS `month`, count(ID) as posts FROM $wpdb->posts $join $where GROUP BY YEAR(post_date), MONTH(post_date) ORDER BY post_date DESC $limit";
        $key = md5($query);
        $cache = wp_cache_get( 'wp_custom_archive' , 'general');
        if ( !isset( $cache[ $key ] ) ) {
            $arcresults = $wpdb->get_results($query);
            $cache[ $key ] = $arcresults;
            wp_cache_set( 'wp_custom_archive', $cache, 'general' );
        } else {
            $arcresults = $cache[ $key ];
        }
        if ( $arcresults ) {
            $afterafter = $after;
            foreach ( (array) $arcresults as $arcresult ) {
                $url = get_month_link( $arcresult->year, $arcresult->month );
                /* translators: 1: month name, 2: 4-digit year */
                $text = sprintf(__('%s'), $wp_locale->get_month($arcresult->month));
                $year_text = sprintf('<li>%d</li>', $arcresult->year);
                if ( $show_post_count )
                    $after = '&nbsp;('.$arcresult->posts.')' . $afterafter;
                $output .= ( $arcresult->year != $temp_year ) ? $year_text : '';
                $output .= get_archives_link($url, $text, $format, $before, $after);

                $temp_year = $arcresult->year;
            }
        }

    $output .= '</ul>';

    if ( $echo )
        echo $output;
    else
        return $output;
}
```

Now you can use `wp_custom_archive` function wherever in your theme:

```
<?php wp_custom_archive(); ?>
```

Comment: Really thanks it works! Do you know how I can do to show just the year's text, not the link? Thanks!

Comment: @Antonio I updated the post with "just the year's text" version.

Comment: This is a long shot but i'm trying to add a category argument for the 'wp_parse_args' to display only the months that have a particular category and it doesn't affect the display. I've tried to use category, custom fields and tag parameters without success. Any idea?